# Laravel-elixir. Versioning without keeping original files

Tags: laravel, laravel-elixir

Is there any way to make versioned files without keeping originals? I want to merge files and make versioned ones without keeping merged, but not versioned copies in public directory. I would like to avoid files duplication. I guess that I can use underlying gulp functions to generate result files through the stream, but maybe there is elixir-way for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep your compiled files and versioned files in separate directories. After versioning, you can clear the *compiled* directory if you want to.

Comment: Should compiled files be placed in public directory, or versioned ones only? I use only versioned styles and scripts. I guess, compiled, but not versioned files should be moved to resources/ directory or any other from public/. So, I should keep only versioned files in public access, right?

Comment: That's all up to you. I prefer them in `public` directory because I don't want them in my Git repository. Cause if they are in `resources` I cannot mass-add the directory like `git add resources/` and will have to add them one by one.